# Which hashing algorithm does .NET use and am I able to perform a password check on these hashes with java

Tags: java, asp.net, hash, mule

I have a legacy webapplication built with ASP.NET 2.0. There is a user registration process implemented in this application and usernames and passwords are stored to a SQL Server database.The passwords are hashed as it was to expect. Although I am not a very experienced .NET programmer, I guess that the System.Security.Cryptography assembly does the job.

Now we want to reuse this user database for other services (basically a SAML Identity Proider would be ideal). I would like to use a combination of Mule ESB and Java Code to do this, but do I even have a chance to hash a password in java the same way .NET does and check this hash on my user database? Has anybody done this already?

**EDIT:** I have further investigated the legacy app. I created an 'Testuser' with the password 'stackoverflow'. In the database I have 2 fields, one named "Password" and one name "EncryptionToken".

For the credentials above 'stackoverflow' becomes

> Password: F545C9A2670C9C261C657CC48AA8F91F284DD824B8142466DB7370FF4A30D741
>   SecurityToken: tn+nms4=

The code for persisting the user password looks like this:

```
public void SetEncryptedPassword(Account user, string password)
{
    user.SecurityToken = CryptoProviderBase.GenerateRandomSalt();
    var hash = new SHA256HashBuilder { Text = password, Salt = user.SecurityToken };
        user.Password = hash.CalculateHash();
}
```

So the hash seems to be a SHA256 hash with a random salt which is stored in SecurityToken.

Unfortunately I am not able (dont have a clue) how to reproduce this in Java. Can you give me some hints?

Comment: You need to find out encryption algorithm which .NET uses. However, in java it is difficult to decrypt the same.

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700702/asp-net-membership-saves-changed-password-as-plain-text-even-with-hashed-passwor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have solved it by myself just by deep investigating (decompiling) some code and think and try around. There is an [online SHA-256 calculator](http://www.xorbin.com/tools/sha256-hash-calculator) I used for this.

If I type in the SecurityToken/[Salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) "tn+nms4=" first and appended the password "stackoverflow" to it. Hashing this then. I got exactly the hash which is stored in the database.

Looks like the implementation of the encrytion provider which is used in the legacy app isn't plain .NET at all but more likely something self crafted.