# using selective tables in asp.net core identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I want to use aspnetusers, aspnetuserroles, aspnetroles tables from asp.net identity in asp.net core applications using code first. I don't want to use claims and other tables but When I try to exclude them and create migration/update-database, I get foreign key constraint errors.

Another thing is that I want to use the plain password with asp.net identity.How Can I use this?

Please suggest.

Comment: Asp.Net Identity is giving you a more or less secure and working foundation to build upon. Why you'd want to rip out the security bits and pieces is beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't pick and choose Identity components. You don't have *use* them all, but all the tables come along for the ride. Just the way it is.
2. You can't use plain text passwords with Identity, and for good reason. You should *never* be storing a password in plain text. I have no idea why you'd even want to.

Answer (score -1):

**I get foreign key constraint errors**

It is related to SQL, you need to understand/read SQL constraint to overcome that issue (Primary key foreign key etc.)

**Another thing is that I want to use the plain password with asp.net identity.How Can I use this?**

you can get more information for this [ASP.Net Membership saves changed password as plain text even with Hashed passwordFormat set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700702/asp-net-membership-saves-changed-password-as-plain-text-even-with-hashed-passwor/25751404#25751404)